# uncaught reference error chart not defined

Tags: jquery

When I run the below code. I just see //replace this with your jQuery version. I tried looking the reason for it in developer tools and see the error "Uncaught reference error :Chart is not defined" . Can someone please help with this?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script src="/js/keylines.js"></script>
        <script src="/js/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>//replace this with your jQuery version
        <link rel=" stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/keylines.css">
        <div id ="kl" style="width: 818px; height: 586px;"></div>
  <script>
    window.onload = function () {
        KeyLines.paths({
            assets: 'assets/',
            flash: {
                swf: 'swf/keylines.swf',
                swfObject: 'js/swfobject.js',
                expressInstall: 'swf/expressInstall.swf'
            }
        });
                $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "JSONFile.json",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (json) {
                ParseJSONData(json, chart);
            }
        });
        function ParseJSONData(obj, chart) {
            // Set up the properties of the chart data object
            var chartData = {
                type: 'LinkChart',
                items: []
            };

            // Convert the loaded object to KeyLines chart format - first the nodes
            for (var i = 0; i < obj.nodes.length; i++) {
                var node = obj.nodes[i];
                // Push node object in KeyLines format onto the items array
                chartData.items.push({
                    id: node.id,
                    type: 'node',
                    t: node.name,
                    c: node.color
                });
            }

            // Now add items for the links
            for (var j = 0; j < obj.links.length; j++) {
                var link = obj.links[j];
                // Push link object in KeyLines format onto the items array
                chartData.items.push({
                    id: link.id,
                    type: 'link',
                    id1: link.from,
                    id2: link.to,
                    w: link.strength   // Use the strength property to set the link width
                });
            }

            // Load the data into the chart, and then perform a layout
            chart.load(chartData, chart.layout);
        }
    };

</script>
  </body>

</html>
```

Below is JSONFile.json as well 
This is the JSONFile.json mentioned in code {

```
  "nodes": [
  {
      "id": "1",
      "name": "Charles",
      "color": "blue"
  },
  {
      "id": "2",
      "name": "Grace",
      "color": "black"
  },
  {
      "id": "3",
      "name": "Stephen",
      "color": "red"
  },
  {
      "id": "4",
      "name": "Carlos",
      "color": "green"
  }
  ],
  "links": [
  {
      "id": "5",
      "from": "1",
      "to": "4",
      "strength": "4"
  },
  {
      "id": "6",
      "from": "4",
      "to": "3",
      "strength": "1"
  },
  {
      "id": "7",
      "from": "2",
      "to": "4",
      "strength": "10"
  },
  {
      "id": "8",
      "from": "2",
      "to": "3",
      "strength": "1"
  }
  ]

}
```

Comment: considering there is no `Chart` in your code here, it's probably in one of the source files that we can't see.

Comment: I added the JSONFile code as well

Comment: In particular you may want to look in the `js/keylines.js` file since that's the one I don't recognize here.  There was another answer here a minute ago that had a good point - you're referencing an undeclared variable in your AJAX success handler - remove the word `chart` from that.  It isn't the same as `Chart` but try it anyway.

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems in your code:

1) the code it is not creating any chart with KeyLines, just setting the paths

```
KeyLines.create( 'element-id', callback);
```

In your case I'd say to wrap the AJAX call in a function and put the function name as callback.

2) a `var chart` variable is missing inside the `ParseJSON` function.

Please contact the KeyLines support for further questions.

(**Note**: I'm in the KeyLines team)